# Sitecore Horizon for 10.3 (not Managed Cloud)

Tags: experience-editor, horizon

As [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/what%27s-new/deprecated-features-in-xp-10-3.html) documentation page states, Sitecore Horizon got obsolete in 10.3. Unfortunately, there is no any info what to use instead for Sitecore 10.3, k8s, (not Managed Cloud). Is going back to Experience Editor the only option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Sitecore decided that Horizon will no longer be supported.

See release notes of Sitecore 10.3: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/103/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%20103/Release%20Notes

> **Horizon End-of-Support with SXP 10.3**
>
> Sitecore is discontinuing support for the Horizon visual page builder beginning with the SXP 10.3 release. If you are using Horizon, you should remain on 10.2, as an upgrade to 10.3 or later will cause you to lose access to Horizon.